# Missing field 'episodes' while writing result

Tags: typescript, next.js, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to consume the Anilist api using graphql in nextjs 13. I'm using the apollo client.
the problem that some fields are not being returned, and the console returns all the others with the error `Missing field 'episodes' while writing result`, which is the case with ID and EPISODES

apollo client:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client'

export const anilistClient = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'https://graphql.anilist.co',
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

query:

```
export const GET_ANIMES_PAGE = gql`
  query getAnimesPerPage($page: Int, $perPage: Int) {
    Page(page: $page, perPage: $perPage) {
      pageInfo {
        total
        currentPage
        hasNextPage
      }
      media {
        id
        coverImage {
          medium
        }
        title {
          english
          native
        }
        format
        seasonYear
        status
        episodes
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

function to get animes

```
export async function getAnimesPerPage(page: number, perPage: number) {
  const { data } = await anilistClient.query({
    query: GET_ANIMES_PAGE,
    variables: {
      page,
      perPage,
    }
  })

  return data.Page.media
}
```

result:

```
Missing field 'episodes' while writing result {
  "coverImage": {
    "medium": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/small/bx19-ham53gnijfiN.jpg",
    "__typename": "MediaCoverImage"
  },
  "title": {
    "english": "Monster",
    "native": "MONSTER",
    "__typename": "MediaTitle"
  },
  "__typename": "Media"
}
```

I tried to set some typePolicies in client settings, but I didn't quite understand how I could do it

Comment: Are there subfields under `episodes`? If so you'll need to include at least one of them.

Comment: In this case there are no subfields for episode, it just returns a number